# App deployment to cloud fails after upgrading to JDK 7

Tags: google-app-engine

Since deployment was not allowed with JDK 1.6, I recently moved to JDK 7 and appengine-java-sdk-1.9.4 .
With JDK 7 (JRE 7) everyting works fine on my local development app engine. But when I upload the application to google cloud  the deployment fails with below errors.

```
    org/apache/jsp/nodecorate/sample_jsp : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0, java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/jsp/test_jsp : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:656)
```

do I need to change the application settings to reflect JRE 7 on google could?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `major.minor version 52.0` indicates that your code was compiled under Java 8. GAE production environment runs Java 7.